# What does the "it" refer to?

Tags: small-soldiers-1998

In science fiction movie "*Small Soldiers (1998)*", Captain Chip Hazard said to his soldiers after declaring a war on Gorgonites and the humans who are shielding the Gorgonites  :

> Commandos, secure the perimeter! Tap all communications! Roll some
>   armor! We got us a war to win. If **it** launches, lacerates or
>   detonates...I want **it** mobile and I want **it** lethal!

Comment: i think he's talking about anything they can weaponize. if something launches stuff, cuts stuff up or blows stuff up he wants it able to be moved and deadly (ie. a pop gun launches suckers, he wants it to be moved and shooting something deadly like nails or razor blades)

Comment: From an English-language perspective this is the same use of "it" as a wildcard as seen in the perhaps more familiar phrase "if it moves, shoot it".

Comment: To whomever voted to close as off-topic, [this is, in fact, sci fi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0122718/)

Comment: Yeah, the *movie* is sci-fi, but the *question* seems to be more about English language comprehension.

Comment: @Steve-O like I’ve recently said on meta, there’s no “rule” to say non-science-fictional and fantastical question about works of science fiction and fantasy are off topic, otherwise we better get closing >50% of the site.

Comment: Hmmm, this question sounds suspiciously like a regular on the M&TV SE, where he also posts questions that are caused by his lack of English comprehension. His account regularly gets a "time out" because his questions attract many downvotes and get closed, and he has a habit of creating new accounts to bypass such blocks.

Comment: @BCdotWEB - I really don't see why the occasional questions of this sort should attract downvotes or censure. It's a perfectly sensible question.

Comment: _If it walks like a duck, quacks like a duck, and looks like a duck; it's probably a duck._ Notice that we don't know "it". It basically means "any object you come across".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "it" in this sentence is any non-lethal toy or game that can be turned into a weapon.

You could rewrite the sentence (without losing any of the meaning) as:

> *If you find anything that launches, lacerates or detonates, I want you
>   to make that thing mobile and lethal.*

This obviously applies to the various toys you see them using later; various catapults, nerf-guns with sharpened ammo, missile-firing RC trucks, etc.